Normal-normal maximum likelihood estimation: Consistency under misspecification
I'm trying to understand the consistency properties of a maximum likelihood estimator in a context with misspecification. Let $i \in \{1,...,N\}$ index units. Assume that:
(1) $X_i | \theta_i,\tau_i^2\overset{\text{ind}}{\sim} N(\theta_i,\tau_i^2)$
(2) $\theta_i | \beta \overset{\text{ind}}{\sim} G(\beta)$
Assume further (and perhaps naively) that $G$ is the normal distribution, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$:
(3) $\theta_i|\mu,\sigma^2 \overset{\text{ind}}{\sim} N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
We observe $\{x_i, \tau_i^2\}_{i=1}^N$. The goal is to estimate the hyperparameters $\beta = (\mu,\sigma^2)$
Noting that under equations (1) and (3):
(4) $X_i | \tau_i^2, \mu,\sigma^2 \overset{\text{ind}}{\sim} N(\mu, \tau_i^2 + \sigma^2)$
we estimate the parameters via maximum likelihood, yielding $(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}^2)$.
I'm trying to understand the conditions under which this MLE is consistent for the mean and variance of $\theta_i$, i.e.:
$(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}^2) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} (E(\theta_i), \text{Var}(\theta_i))$
Under standard regularity conditions, this will hold when $G$ is in fact the normal distribution.
Will it also hold if $G$ is non-normal?
It appears that there are at least some conditions under which it will. For example, when $\tau_1^2 = ... \tau_N^2 = \tau^2$, then:
$(\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma}^2) = (\bar{x}, \frac{1}{N}\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2 - \tau^2) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} (E(\theta_i), \text{Var}(\theta_i))$

What is $G(\beta)$ if $G$ is supposed to be the normal distribution?

I'm interested in the setting where our estimator is motivated by the assumption that $G$ is normal but $G$ actually is not normal in practice.
